# Installing LitleOnline Gem changes ActionMailer email whitespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I have a Rails 4 project with an ActionMailer and related tests that pass. The tests check the exact HTML email body.

While doing some work unrelated to email, I need to install the [LitleOnline](https://rubygems.org/gems/LitleOnline) gem for payment processing. I add

```
gem 'LitleOnline'
```

to my Gemfile, and run

```
bundle install --path vendor
```

My Gemfile.lock shows these new gems:

```
LitleOnline (8.19.0)
crack (0.4.2)
safe_yaml (1.0.3)
libxml-ruby (2.7.0)
net-sftp (2.1.2)
net-ssh (2.9.1)
xml-mapping (0.9.1)
xml-object (0.9.93)
```

Now my ActionMailer tests fail because the whitespace in the HTML output is different. I get a bunch of diffs like:

```
-\t\t\t\t\t</tr></table></div>
+\t\t\t\t\t</tr>
+
+\t\t\t</table></div>
```

The really weird part is that if I `bundle exec gem uninstall xxx` all of the new gems, the tests still fail!

**How are the new gems affecting the whitespace of my email?**

Comment: This is repeatable with a fresh clone of the repository that has no other changes.

Comment: What is in your email?

Comment: It's a big ERB blob of HTML.

Comment: related to an order?  That's the only reason I can see it would be affecting it.